# How to stretch QSvgWidget in GridLayout

Tags: python, svg, layout, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I was trying to add background image under my svg widget, however after putting one widget into another it was sqeezed to its minimal width. For resizing I'm using resize event which doesn't work anymore after updating widget.

Normal size widget:
[image: Normal size widget]

Sqeezed widget:
[image: Sqeezed widget]

```
class GoodSize(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)

        self.gridLayout_main = QGridLayout(self)
        self.widgetSvg = QSvgWidget()
        self.widgetSvg.setStyleSheet("background-color:white;")
        self.gridLayout_main.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.gridLayout_main.addWidget(self.widgetSvg)


class Squeezed(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)

        self.gridLayout_main = QGridLayout(self)
        self.widgetSvg = QSvgWidget()
        self.widgetSvg.setStyleSheet("background-color:white;")
        self.gridLayout_main.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        
        self.wallpaper = QWidget()
        self.wallpaper_grid = QGridLayout(self.wallpaper)
        self.wallpaper_grid.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.gridLayout_main.addWidget(self.wallpaper)
        self.wallpaper_grid.addWidget(self.widgetSvg)

        self.wallpaper.setStyleSheet(".QWidget{\n"
            "border-image: url(:/Images/background.JPG) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;\n"
            "background-position: center;\n"
            "background-repeat: none;\n"
            "}\n"
            "}")

# Resize event slot
    @pyqtSlot(QWidget)
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.widgetSvg.setFixedWidth(self.widgetSvg.height())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found solution to this problem. I had to use show event and resize svg widget there

```
@pyqtSlot(QWidget)
    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.widgetSvg.setFixedWidth(self.widgetSvg.height())
```